# Parse LUIS builtin.datetime.date

Tags: c#, datetime, bots, azure-language-understanding

I have built a Luis model, and I have encountered issues parsing the builtin.datetime.date for an entry like "this weeked" returns 2016-W20-WE (or something similar) which doesnt parse successfuly using DateTime.Parse.

I came across this [post](http://www.lonniebgood.com/blog/2016/4/22/pibot-hackathon-2016-a-natural-language-interface-to-the-pi.html) which seems to use a class called LUISParse, but I can't find any reference to this on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem and see that in their sdk doc they use Chronic on the actual entity string rather than trying to interpret the date format. [See Here](http://docs.botframework.com/sdkreference/csharp/dialogs.html#alarmBot):

So I did something like this:

```
Chronic.Parser parser = new Chronic.Parser();
EntityRecommendation date = new EntityRecommendation();
luisResponse.TryFindEntity("builtin.datetime.date", out date);
var dateResult = parser.Parse(date.Entity);
```

It works since the date.Entity only contains the date related string. Ex: I pass in "Yes I am planning to go next week" to Luis and the entity contains "next week".

Comment: perfect. returns a Chronic.Span with Start, End nullable datetime properties.

Comment: this is really good - but, it doesn't seem to work with the builtin.datetime.duration - next 7 days comes back as today's date with 7am through to 7:01am

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use the raw value, I've found I had to dig into the internal elements and use the "value", "start" and "end" properties. Those properties at least follow date formats. This works for durations such as Weekend or Next 3 Days as well as Today and specific date requests.

```
            if (entity.Type == "builtin.datetimeV2.daterange")
            {
                var resolutionValues = (IList<object>)entity.Resolution["values"];
                foreach (var value in resolutionValues)
                {
                    _start = Convert.ToDateTime(((IDictionary<string, object>)value)["start"]);
                    _end = Convert.ToDateTime(((IDictionary<string, object>)value)["end"]);
                }
            }
            else if (entity.Type == "builtin.datetimeV2.date")
            {
                var resolutionValues = (IList<object>)entity.Resolution["values"];
                foreach (var value in resolutionValues)
                {
                    _when = Convert.ToDateTime(((IDictionary<string, object>)value)["value"]);
                }
            }
```